# While dropping a table, "trigger 'MDSYS.SDO_TOPO_DROP_FTBL' is invalid and failed re-validation" in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, spatial

DROP TABLE ATTACHMENT PURGE; this query gives the below error in Oracle 12c DB.
Can anyone please help me resolve this issue.

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DROP TABLE ATTACHMENT_REF PURGE
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'MDSYS.SDO_TOPO_DROP_FTBL' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Comment: Seems it was some problem while deleting Oracle Spatial. Do you want complete delete this feature or restore it functionality?

Comment: I want to delete the entire table.

Comment: You cann't delete table because feature Oracle Spatial hasn't removed correctly or it is in inconsistent state. I assume you will encounter the same problem or more exotic once again.

Comment: Possibly this issue:
http://www.dadbm.com/unable-to-ddl-due-to-oracle-spatial-and-xdb/

Comment: @Rene I think it be no other but e'en so

Comment: if I drop the trigger MDSYS.SDO_TOPO_DROP_FTBL, it works. Does it affect the DB anyway.